# Is changing roots primary group dangerous?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, groups, usermod

Currently in CentOS 7 the root user's primary group is root. What harm would there be in changing roots primary group to group.

```
usermod -a -g group root
```

The purpose just to clarify in case there is a much better way of handling this is to make sure the ownership is set to root:group instead of root:root without having to add chown after every single file is created.

Comment: Is your intention to have all of the files that currently have root:root ownership to be transformed into root:group ownership?  Or is your question about the effects of altering the root user's default group?

Comment: @toppledwagon I do not have any intention of changing the root:root ownership of current files. I am only interested in the effects of altering the root user's primary group.

Comment: I've never tried this, but I can't think of any ill effects.  Of course that doesn't mean that there aren't any!  Is this just a curiosity or do you have an application for this in mind?